# ElasticSearch (java) - Nodes not configured issue

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I'm trying the most basic case to connect to my ES cluster, but it seems that the host I register are not being registered. This is the code I'm running:

```
//Create the client
Client client = new TransportClient(ImmutableSettings.builder()
    .put("cluster.name", "MyCluster")
    .put("client.transport.sniff","true").build())
    .addTransportAddresses(
        new InetSocketTransportAddress("host1", 9300),
        new InetSocketTransportAddress("host2", 9300));

// Try to make a call
SearchRequest sr = new SearchRequest().indices("MyIndex");
ActionFuture<SearchResponse> search = client.search(sr);
SearchResponse actionGet = search.actionGet(); // <-- Exception
System.out.println(actionGet.toString());

client.close();
```

This is the exception I get:

**Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException:

None of the configured nodes are available: []**

It looks like it there is no connected nodes, what am I missing?

NOTE: I'm using the elastic search client with gradle:
*compile 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:1.7.5'*

Comment: Is your cluster working properly? Does the versions of yout client and server same/compatible?

Comment: The cluster is working fine with REST calls. And I think I have the same versions, how do I check the version on the server?

Comment: Just type `curl -XGET 'http://host:9200`. Also check for cluster name.

Comment: You right, it was a version error. Thanks.

Comment: @Gavirel I also answer the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some possible reasons for this:

- The client and server versions can be different
- Cluster name can be different
- There could be a network problem when accesing the host and port.